# Convert string of lat lon to geojson polygon

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
col_a   col_b   col_c   lat lon polyline                                                            
0   2.2 3/27/2017 17:45 -34.92967678    -62.34831333    [{lat":-34.92967677667683   lng:-62.34831333160395} {"lat":-34.93002861969753   lng:-62.360866069793644}    {"lat":-34.93526211379422   lng:-62.36063016609785} {"lat":-34.93571078689853   lng:-62.35996507775451} {"lat":-34.935798629937075  lng:-62.34816312789911} {"lat":-34.9333358703344    lng:-62.34824895858759} {"lat":-34.9320340961022    lng:-62.348334789276066}]"      
0   3.3 3/27/2017 17:45 -34.92967678    -62.34831333    [{lat":-34.92967677667683   lng:-62.34831333160395} {"lat":-34.93002861969753   lng:-62.360866069793644}    {"lat":-34.93526211379422   lng:-62.36063016609785} {"lat":-34.93571078689853   lng:-62.35996507775451} {"lat":-34.935798629937075  lng:-62.34816312789911} {"lat":-34.9333358703344    lng:-62.34824895858759} {"lat":-34.9320340961022    lng:-62.348334789276066}]"
```

I would like to convert it into a geopandas dataframe (with geometry information from polyline), but the polyline column is not in a  standard format. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, if the original dataframe is a Pandas dataframe, then you can try using [Series.str.translate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.translate.html?highlight=translate#pandas.Series.str.translate) to remove all double quotes and use [Series.str.findall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html?highlight=findall) to retrieve all lat-long pairs into a list of tuples and then assign coordinates to create the Polygon(notice we use `map(float,x)` to convert lat/long from str to float):

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

df['coords'] = df.polyline \
    .str.translate(str.maketrans({'"':''})) \
    .str.findall(r'\blat:(-?\d+\.\d+)\s+lng:(-?\d+\.\d+)')

geometry = [ Polygon([(float(x), float(y)) for x,y in e]) for e in df['coords'] ]

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.drop(['coords','polyline'], axis=1), geometry=geometry)
```

**Edit:** if the methods under `pandas.Series.str` are not available, you can do the same using Python re module, for example: (assume the original dataframe is a geodataframe named gdf)

```
import re
ptn = re.compile(r'\blat:(-?\d+\.\d+)\s+lng:(-?\d+\.\d+)')
geometry = [ Polygon(tuple(map(float,x)) for x in re.findall(ptn, x.replace('"',''))) for e in gdf["polyline"] ]
gdf_new = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf, geometry=geometry)
```

Comment: thanks @jxc, it is a geodataframe and not pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1):

The code suggested by `@jxc` also works if the data is already in a GeoDataFrame as GeoPandas support string operations.

Here is a piece of code to re-create the GeoDataFrame

```
from io import StringIO #Python 3 
import pandas as pd 
import geopandas as gpd 

df_string="""0;2.2;3/27/2017 17:45;-34.92967678;-62.34831333;[{lat":-34.92967677667683   lng:-62.34831333160395} {"lat":-34.93002861969753   lng:-62.360866069793644}    {"lat":-34.93526211379422   lng:-62.36063016609785} {"lat":-34.93571078689853   lng:-62.35996507775451} {"lat":-34.935798629937075  lng:-62.34816312789911} {"lat":-34.9333358703344    lng:-62.34824895858759} {"lat":-34.9320340961022    lng:-62.348334789276066}]"       0;3.3;3/27/2017 17:45;-34.92967678;-62.34831333;[{lat":-34.92967677667683   lng:-62.34831333160395} {"lat":-34.93002861969753   lng:-62.360866069793644}    {"lat":-34.93526211379422   lng:-62.36063016609785} {"lat":-34.93571078689853   lng:-62.35996507775451} {"lat":-34.935798629937075  lng:-62.34816312789911} {"lat":-34.9333358703344    lng:-62.34824895858759} {"lat":-34.9320340961022    lng:-62.348334789276066}]" """

df_io = StringIO(df_string)
df = pd.read_csv(df_io, sep=";", names=["col_a","col_b","col_c","lat","lon","polyline"])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)
```

Which results in

```
gdf
    col_a   col_b   col_c   lat lon polyline
0   0   2.2 3/27/2017 17:45 -34.92967678    -62.34831333    "[{lat"":-34.92967677667683   lng:-62.34831333160395} {""lat"":-34.93002861969753   lng:-62.360866069793644}    {""lat"":-34.93526211379422   lng:-62.36063016609785} {""lat"":-34.93571078689853   lng:-62.35996507775451} {""lat"":-34.935798629937075  lng:-62.34816312789911} {""lat"":-34.9333358703344    lng:-62.34824895858759} {""lat"":-34.9320340961022    lng:-62.348334789276066}]""      "
1   0   3.3 3/27/2017 17:45 -34.92967678    -62.34831333    "[{lat"":-34.92967677667683   lng:-62.34831333160395} {""lat"":-34.93002861969753   lng:-62.360866069793644}    {""lat"":-34.93526211379422   lng:-62.36063016609785} {""lat"":-34.93571078689853   lng:-62.35996507775451} {""lat"":-34.935798629937075  lng:-62.34816312789911} {""lat"":-34.9333358703344    lng:-62.34824895858759} {""lat"":-34.9320340961022    lng:-62.348334789276066}]"""
```

Then, if the geometry is a Line as suggested by the *polyline* column name, you should use Shapely `LineString` method instead of `Polygon`:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
coords = gdf.polyline \
    .str.translate(str.maketrans({'"':''})) \
    .str.findall(r'\blat:(-?\d+\.\d+)\s+lng:(-?\d+\.\d+)')

gdf.geometry = [ LineString([(float(x), float(y)) for x,y in e]) for e in coords ]
```

As both the geometry are the same, we can plot the first one:

```
gdf[0:1].plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made it for you.

```
import json
lat_lon_str = '''[{"lat": -32.436756736154024, "lng": -62.17932943721189},
               {"lat": -32.445847463649905, "lng": -62.18160395045652},
               {"lat": -32.44686151186612, "lng": -62.176711601213356},
               {"lat": -32.44721472434227, "lng": -62.17625005841933},
               {"lat": -32.44387381345414, "lng": -62.17003797011375},
               {"lat": -32.44158302782885, "lng": -62.16614345534663},
               {"lat": -32.43979915340108, "lng": -62.16164831538572}]'''

lat_lon_json = json.loads(lat_lon_str)
coords = ["POINT({} {})".format(round(line['lat'], 2), round(line['lng'], 2)) for line in lat_lon_json]
print(coords)
```

The result:

[image]
After testing it, if the result is what you want, please let me know.

Comment: thanks @Ahmed! I am testing, one quick comment, it should be a POLYGON and not POINT

Comment: Did you get any result?